# Calling constructor of potential child from base in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overriding

How can someone implement this pattern:

```
  class Base {//doesn't know anything about potential descendant-classes, like Child
  public:
      Base * foo( void) {
        //some code
          return ( Base *) new !Child-constructor!();
      }
  };

  class Child : public Base { };

//—————————————————————————————————————————————————
  #include <iostream>
  #include <typeinfo>

  using namespace std;

  int main( void) {
      Base * base_p = Child().f();

      cout << typeid( *base_p).name(); //expected to get "Child"

  return 0;
  }
```

I can't find the right syntax for this type of constructions (calling the "potential" child constructor).

**UPD**: I forgot to mention (didn't think that there can be missunderstanding), that `Child` class must not be known in definition of `Base`. So I wanted `foo` to call the constructor of the class in which it's gonna be inherited.

Comment: Forgot to say, I can't use C++11.

Comment: The definition of `foo` requires the definition of `Child`. The definition of `Child` requires the definition of `Base`, which only requires a declaration of `foo`. No problems here.

Comment: So what should I write in place of `!Child-constructor!()`?

Comment: `Child`, just like you use in `main`.

Comment: Did you you `clone()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"... that Child class must not be known in definition of Base. So I wanted foo to call the constructor of the class in which it's gonna be inherited."*

IMHO the easiest way is to provide a [**templated factory function**](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method/cpp/1) with `Base`

```
class Base {
public:
    template<class Derived>
    static std::unique_ptr<Base> foo( void) {
      //some code
      return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived());
    }
};

class Child : public Base {
public:
    Child() {}
    virtual ~Child() {}
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> p = Base::foo<Child>();
    return 0;
}
```

Check the compilable sample [here please](http://ideone.com/iWM33T).

Comment: Thank you, I think it's what I will use.

Answer (score 0):

This design is awful, btw.

```
 //terriblecode.hpp

 struct Base
 {
    Base * foo(void);
 };

 struct Child : public Base{};

 //terriblecode.cpp
 Base* Base::foo() {return (Base*) new Child();}
```

The definition of child isn't needed untill the definition of foo. Separate your declaration from your definition of member functions, and it is pretty easy to do.

Comment: Ditch the C-style cast, upcast is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to make sure you let the compiler know about your derived class before the first use:

```
class Child; // forward declaration

class Base {
public:
  Base * foo( void);
};

class Child : public Base { };

// the function needs to be defined after the "Child" is known
Base * Base::foo( void) {
  //some code
    return new Child; // will be automatically type-cast to base class
}

//—————————————————————————————————————————————————
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main( void) {
  Base * base_p = Child().f();

  cout << typeid( *base_p).name(); //expected to get "Child"

  return 0;
}
```

However, I'd recommend a different pattern:

```
class Child; // forward declaration

class Base {
public:
  static Base * foo( void); // static "factory" method
};

class Child : public Base { };

// the function needs to be defined after the "Child" is known
Base * Base::foo( void) {
  //some code
    return new Child; // will be automatically type-cast to base class
}

//—————————————————————————————————————————————————
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main( void) {
  Base * base_p = Base::f(); // use scope resolution, not object's method

  cout << typeid( *base_p).name(); //expected to get "Child"

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course :) Make it out of line. Lemme change it RQ

Comment: The forward declaration isn't contributing anything.

Comment: @YePhIcK, Thanks for the answer, but I forgot to mention (didn't think that there can be missunderstanding), that `Child` class must not be known in definition of `Base`. So I wanted `foo` to call the constructor of the class in which it's gonna be inherited.